# Showing that $ASPACE(f (n)) = DTIME(2^{O(f (n))})$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

My lecture notes for complexity says that $\mathsf{ASPACE}(f (n)) = \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(f (n))})$

I can prove the forward direction ($\mathsf{ASPACE}(f (n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{O(f (n))})$) by building a computation tree of the alternating Turing machine and rejecting after $\ge 2^{f(n)}$ time steps and then merging nodes of the same configuration at the same level to form a DAG. This allows us to simulate the computation in $2^{O(f (n))}$ steps.

I'm not sure about how to proceed with the reverse direction.

Comment: See Theorem 4 in Madhu Sudan's [lecture notes](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~madhusudan/courses/Spring2018/scribe/lect06.pdf).

Comment: Theorem 4 seems to prove the direction which I've already proven? I don't know how to solve the opposite direction

Comment: Theorem 4 contains both directions.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read it well enough. Thanks!